# What's a better way to return a cell that matches conditionals in two adjacent columns?

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with player names, team names, pts per game, and the rank of a player on their team by scoring.

On another sheet I want to return the pts per game value for specific team names and ranks.

I know I can just sort the list by team name and then copy and past each set of team numbers, but I want to learn how to make Excel do this for me. I know I could use Index and Match if I only had a single conditional (ie, return the pts per game where playername column matches...), but I don't know how to make it check for the team name AND the rank.

I did some googling from my desk, and didn't see any clear answers to what I'm thinking about.

I'd appreciate any pointers. Like I said, I know I can do this manually, but I like learning how to make Excel do this for me.

EDIT:
Here's some screen shots. http://imgur.com/bZX0bP7,JboMmop#1

Comment: If you provide more detail, I could actually write the formula. I suggest you look into `=Sumproduct()`. I believe this will do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @Kyle cool, I'll look and I'll add a screen shot to illustrate my point in a bit.

Comment: @Kyle, Here's a pair of screen shots: http://imgur.com/bZX0bP7,JboMmop#1 .

I'd like to return the value 17 by having a formula check a column for the "ATL" text, and the other column for the "1" value... then I'd iterate it to pull off the top 5 pts per game values for each team from the spreadsheet.

I looked at =Sumproduct() and I don't get how to use it to achieve my goal here, but I'll look at it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have a column of the rank, this is a bit more simple. I am assuming that your "rank" column is column D, "PTS" is column C and "Tm" is column B. In F1, type "ATL", and in F2:F6 enter the numbers 1-5. Now, in cell G2, enter the below formula:

```
=Sumproduct((B:B=$F$1) * (C:C) * (D:D=G2))
```

Now, drag this formula down from F2 to F6 and you will have a rank of the top 5 players for "ATL". You can change "ATL" to any team you choose, and you can change 1-5 to any rank you want.

Comment: great thanks. Your formula worked perfect. I had to address the problem of ties in my data, which I did in a really messy way. I put a heatmap conditional format over the finished table and whenever the scores went up as the rank along the top went down, I knew there was a tie in that part of the data....

Comment: Honestly, I think I'm going to pause on Excel and work on how to do this in R instead, but your help... and the thinking that Sumproduct opened up in my head was great.

Comment: Glad I could help, even if ti isn't your final solution. Using `=Sumproduct()` in this manner is an incredibly useful tool.